# a way to have a callback function when applying .appendTo() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

So I'm having a bit of html code that I'm appending with the jQuery method `.appendTo()`, and after that there's a jQuery plugin running on that html :

```
$(str).appendTo(target);
    self.initiate_jpages_plugin(self.cluster_public_classes.items_navigation, {
        containerID: self.cluster_public_ids.items_wrapper,
        previous: self.cluster_public_classes.previous_items,
        next: self.cluster_public_classes.next_items,
        perPage: 16,
        midRange: 8,
        animation: self.cluster_animations[17],
        links: "blank",
        keyBrowse: true,
        callback: function(pages) {
            /*var data = {
                current_page: pages.current,
                total_pages: pages.count
            }
            self.set_local_storage_data(self.local_storage_key, JSON.stringify(data));*/
        }
    });
```

The above is how it looks, but there are a lot of variables there that don't quite make sense (: I'm only looking for a solution to keep the html hidden for as long as the plugin it's not applied ( the plugin will append all of the html again ), so the best thing I could think of it's a callback function which I know the `.appendTo()` method does not have.

So would there be a workaround for that ?

Comment: Do you want to hide `$(str)` or `target` while the plugin is initializing?

Comment: `.appendTo` is syncronous and the next function waits for it to complete, so it does'nt need a callback ?

Comment: No I just want to keep things on hold until the plugin applies, because otherwise what I have appended will flash ( there are some items on the page and when the plugin a is applied the items will show up with an CSS effect like fade in or other ... so if the items are there before the plugin is applied they will go away and then fade in again )

Comment: @adeneo - Yeah, but I still get the flash thing ...

Comment: Did you try just doing `$(str).hide().appendTo(target);` and let the plugin show it when it's done, if it does in fact have a fadein method?

Comment: OK, but you need the appending to happen before the plugin is applied right? You just want to append hidden content?

Comment: The `str` is actually the HTML ( so it's a string not an ID ), and it's appended to the `target`. If I hide the `target` then I won't get the effect the plugin does ( which is the whole point of the plugin ). And yes, I do need to have the content appended before the plugin does it's work (:

Comment: @Roland Right, so does my answer get you what you need? It basically just hides `$(str)` before appending it and also gives it an id so that you can target it in your plugin's callback function. Could `str` already have an id? In that case, I will update my answer to add a class instead.

Comment: @lbstr ~ Let me try it and I will see if it is indeed the right way to do it (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Instead of adding an id, I'm going to add a class. `$(str)` could be anything and could already have an id. If you are confidant that an id will suffice, feel free to use that instead.**

All I'm doing is hiding `$(str)` and giving it a unique class so that I can target it in the callback and show it. Is that what you were looking for?

```
var uniqueClass = "str" + new Date().getTime();
$(str).addClass(uniqueClass).hide().appendTo(target); 
self.initiate_jpages_plugin(self.cluster_public_classes.items_navigation, {
    containerID: self.cluster_public_ids.items_wrapper,
    previous: self.cluster_public_classes.previous_items,
    next: self.cluster_public_classes.next_items,
    perPage: 16,
    midRange: 8,
    animation: self.cluster_animations[17],
    links: "blank",
    keyBrowse: true,
    callback: function(pages) {
        $('.' + uniqueClass).show(); // show it!
        /*var data = {
            current_page: pages.current,
            total_pages: pages.count
        }
        self.set_local_storage_data(self.local_storage_key, JSON.stringify(data));*/
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried the [ajaxComplete handler?](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Comment: This would also work for other methods not just for AJAX requests ?

Comment: There is no ajax going on anywhere. -1